# mongoose findOne, update and exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am confused how to use mongoose according to the [following documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) using findOne().update().exec() should return a promise but what is returned does not have a fail member:

```
var ret = mongoose.models[collection].findOne({_id:id})
      .update({status:status})
      .exec();
console.log('having fail:',ret.fail);//undefined
console.log('having catch:',ret.catch);//undefined
console.log('having then:',ret.then);//this is defined
```

This is maybe because their promise doesn't implement fail or catch and I have to try setting a reject function on the last .then to see if that will get called:

```
promise.then(returningPromise)
  .then(returningPromise)
  .then(returningPromise)
  .then(null,handleFail)
```

Then I try the following:

```
var ret = mongoose.models[collection].findOne({_id:id})
//      .update({status:status})
        .exec(function(er,dt){
          //callback: null { _id: 000000000000000000000001,...
          console.log('callback:',er,dt);
      });
```

Nice to see I get something but uncomment the update and I get the following:

```
var ret = mongoose.models[collection].findOne({_id:id})
        .update({status:status})
        .exec(function(er,dt){
          //callback: null null
          console.log('callback:',er,dt);
      });
```

The record is not updated either. I understand if no record was found but without the update it does find a record.

So my main question is how to update this record using findOne and update (not findOneAndUpdate) and the second question would be if the reject of the last .then would be called if the the first promise rejects. If not then how do do a catch at the end since mongoose promises do not support fail or catch.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that I have to provide a criteria to update and the following seems to work for me:

```
  return Q().then(function(){
    var d = Q.defer();
    mongoose.models[col].findOne({_id:id})
          .update({_id:id},{status:status})
          .exec(function(e,dt){
              if(e){
                d.reject(e);return;
              }
              d.resolve(dt);
            });
    return d.promise;    
  });
```

Added Q dependency so I can return a promise that doesn't require me to change the calling code.